# MySql:while using GROUP_CONCAT & COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database in which there is a user table & how many time they reward record table I wanna result like this (WEEK WISE)

```
user_name user_week user_reward
abc          24,25,26    4,5,6
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT WEEK(cpd.added_date),COUNT(cpd.result)
FROM cron_players_data cpd WHERE cpd.player_id = 81
AND cpd.result = 2 AND cpd.status = 1
GROUP BY WEEK(cpd.added_date);
```

And Result is

```
user_name user_week user_reward
abc          24    4
abc          24    5
abc          24    6
```

i use group_concat with count but its useless is there any alternate method for this desire result

Comment: The `user_*` columns do not appear in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 level grouping, first week, and then username,
so i sugest you use a subquery for that first grouping like:

```
SELECT
 user_name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(user_week) AS user_weeks, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(user_reward) AS user_rewards
FROM (
  SELECT
   user_name,
   WEEK(cpd.added_date) AS user_week,
   COUNT(cpd.result) AS user_reward
  FROM cron_players_data AS cpd 
  WHERE
   cpd.player_id = 81 AND
   cpd.result = 2 AND
   cpd.status = 1
  GROUP BY user_week
) as temp
GROUP BY user_name;
```